# Hangfire exception forces application to crash

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, hangfire

I am getting below exception

```
Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more hosted services failed to stop. (The operation was canceled.)
 ---> System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at Hangfire.Processing.TaskExtensions.WaitOneAsync(WaitHandle waitHandle, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken token)
   at Hangfire.Processing.BackgroundDispatcher.WaitAsync(TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundProcessingServer.WaitForShutdownAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.WaitForShutdownAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.Run(String url
```

`Asp.net core version 6.0.3`

`Hangfire.core  Version 1.7.28 Hangfire.Aspnetcore version 1.7.28`

I have asp.net core application with Hangfire integrated with it
sudo code:

**startup.cs**
**ConfigureServices method**
`services.AddHangfire();`
`services.AddHangfireServer();`

**Configure method**
`app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire");`

Research and analysis till now,
As exception is thrown `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StopAsync` I understand that hangfire a hosted service internally and that causes an issue.

possible solution could be if the above service is my custom hosted service i could have wrapped it
under a `IHostedService` service and could have handled the exception as below eg

```
public class MyHostedServiceWrapper : IHostedService
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyHostedServiceWrapper> _logger;
    private readonly IHostedService _innerService;

    public MyHostedServiceWrapper(ILogger<MyHostedServiceWrapper> logger, IHostedService innerService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _innerService = innerService;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            await _innerService.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while starting the hosted service");
        }
    }

    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            await _innerService.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while stopping the hosted service");
        }

        // Return a completed task to indicate that the service has stopped
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

But that is not the case.
I just want to skip the above exception without crashing the application

Comment: please post the code you are trying to run (and how you try to cancel it) as a backrground task

Comment: I do not cancel the task and i don't have control over the hangfire fire internal execution
and exception is thrown  `Hangfire.Processing.TaskExtensions.WaitOneAsync` at here.

Comment: I doubt the most simple solution to your problem is replacing Hangfire hosted service.
You should first look at your code and try to figure out why it makes hangfire crash.
Please post the code you are trying to run as a background job. Interesting points would be if this code features things like async void calls, or new threads.

Comment: @jbl, I do not have code as such, this is all happening internal to hangfire where I don't have control.